# Concat de dos campos en distintas filas - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, concat

Tengo la tabla `Adjudicacion` la cual lleva varios datos, entre ellos `no_garantia`, y cada fila de la consulta sería una adjudicación. 
Cada adjudicación como dije antes, tiene su tipo de garantia (normal, profesional o ambas). Si la adjudicación tiene los dos tipos de garantía, la consulta me da dos filas idénticas excepto en `no_garantia`. Lo que quiero es que me salga solo una adjudicación en vez de dos, pero que en esa adjudicación me salga en el campo `no_garantia` una concatenación de los dos campos `no_garantia` de cada fila idéntica. He intentado hacer un group by `Adjudicacion.ID`, puesto que las adjudicaciones son idénticas en ID también, pero luego no sabría como juntar los datos de las dos filas en un campo...

```
 SELECT 
        PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.ID, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.NU_PROCESO,
PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.NO_PROCESO, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.NU_IMPORTE, 
    PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.ID_TIPO_RIESGO, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.ID_MONEDA, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.ID_SUBGRUPO_PRODUCTO, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.ID_ESTADO, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.ID_SUBESTADO, 
    PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.ID_TIPO_COMPRA, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.FT_ADJUDICACION, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.ID_CONTACTO, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.ID_PETICIONARIO, 
    PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.FT_INICIO_CONTRATO, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.FT_FIN_CONTRATO, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.FT_CAMBIO_ESTADO, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.FT_CAMBIO_SUBESTADO, 
    PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.NU_RECORDATORIOS_ENVIADOS, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.ID_PROVEEDOR,
    PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.IN_GLOBAL, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.IN_CONFORME,PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.IN_CONFIDENCIAL,PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.IN_COMPRA_CONDIC,PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.IN_ACCION,
    PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.TX_OBSERVACIONES, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.TX_OBS_ESTADO,
    PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.IT_VERSION, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.FT_USU_MOD, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.FT_USU_ALTA, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.IN_BAJA, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.NO_USU_ALTA, PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.NO_USU_MOD,PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.NO_GARANTIA 
            FROM PPR_ADJUDICACION_M 
            where PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.ID_VERSION = 3101
        group by PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.ID
```

Comment: Puedes añadir un ejemplo de lo que has intentado? Puedes poner un resultado de cómo lo querrías? Te recomiendo que consultes, [Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @LucasD.A.W. he editado la pregunta, ahí está la consulta

Comment: seria importante ver una imagen de los que deseas lograr.

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo No hace falta, ya te digo que las filas son idénticas excepto en `no_garantia`, una con garantia normal , otra con profesional, lo demás exactamente igual.

Comment: Prueba utilizando la función [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions101.htm#SQLRF30030).

Answer (score 2):

Podrías probar con lo siguiente:

```
SELECT PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.ID,
       LISTAGG(PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.NO_GARANTIA, '; ')
  FROM PPR_ADJUDICACION_M 
  WHERE PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.ID_VERSION = 3101
  GROUP BY PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.ID
```

En este caso los valores de PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.NO_GARANTIA estarían separados por ; y un espacio, pero lo puedes cambiar a lo que tu necesites.

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar la función `CONCAT()` para los campos que quieras unir.

> La función CONCAT() concatena dos o más expresiones en una.

```
    SELECT otros campos... 
           CONCAT(PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.NO_USU_MOD,PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.NO_GARANTIA) as no_garantia 
                FROM PPR_ADJUDICACION_M 
                where PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.ID_VERSION = 3101
            group by PPR_ADJUDICACION_M.ID
```

Te dejo la [documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp).

Comment: Claro, concatenar dos campos de la misma fila si que se hacerlo, lo que no se es hacerlo de distintas filas. Lo que dije antes es que quiero juntar dos filas idénticas excepto en `no_garantia` , y que en el campo `no_garantia`quede concatenados los dos datos de las dos filas.